# Unable to import frameworks inside xcframework

Tags: ios, xcode, xcframework

I have developed an XCFramework, which internally has another third-party framework. For example, consider 'Sample' is the xcframework, it internally has Alamofire framework. Now I am importing this Sample.xcframework in another ios app target now I am not able to access the Alamofire inside the xcframework.

I have added the Framework search path in target settings.
For Simulator:

> $(PROJECT_DIR)/Sample.xcframework/ios-x86_64-simulator/Sample.framework/Frameworks

For iOS devices:

> $(PROJECT_DIR)/Sample.xcframework/ios-arm64/Sample.framework/Frameworks

While building the iOS app it shows the error

- Failed to build module 'Sample' from its module interface; it may
  have been damaged or it may have triggered a bug in the Swift
  compiler when it was produced
- No such module 'Alamofire'

**NOTE**: Alamofire framework is available inside - $(PROJECT_DIR)/Sample.xcframework/ios-arm64/Sample.framework/Frameworks

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution on this?